Kestrel doesn't like trolling the attacker with bogus root escapes much
So I had this brilliant idea to troll the attacker by setting up a nonsense response to faking a path escape.
At one time this used to do something interesting
GET /../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.0


So I wrote:
        app.MapGet("/../../etc/passwd", () => """
root:ZghOT0eRm4U9s:0:0::/:/bin/sh
""");

But it doesn't work at all:
GET /../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 27 Aug 2024 01:51:19 GMT
Server: Kestrel

What's up with that?
(This is an troll app.MapGet() entry to waste a script kiddie's time. If it doesn't ever get fixed, small loss. It uses minimal apis because the whole application will use minimal apis for everything including static file resolution.)

You mean you are trying to request something like http://localhost:5082/../etc/passwd?

This is handled by the Kestrel which turns the /../../etc/passwd path into just /etc/passwd.
From the Kestrel tests, for example Http2/Http3:
// ...
[InlineData("/a/b/c/../d", "/a/b/d")] // Navigation processed
[InlineData("/a/b/c/../../../../d", "/d")] // Navigation escape prevented
// ...
public async Task Path_DecodedAndNormalized(string input, string expected)

hence the "back-navigations" are processed up to the "app root"  but no further, so your route pattern on the application level should be just /etc/passwd:
app.MapGet("/etc/passwd", ...);

UPD

The idea is specifically, /etc/passwd is a 404 but ../../etc/ password returns something

Then you can try getting the "raw target" and for example using conditional handler pipeline (add it somewhere at start of the pipeline):
app.UseWhen(context =>
    {
        var httpRequestFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();
        var rawTarget = httpRequestFeature?.RawTarget;
        return rawTarget == "/../../etc/passwd";
    },
    appBuilder => appBuilder.Run(
       ctx => ctx.Response.WriteAsync("root:ZghOT0eRm4U9s:0:0::/:/bin/sh")));


The idea is specifically, /etc/passwd is a 404 but ../../etc/password returns something so the scanner thinks they found a bug. Anyway, a curiosity, not important.

@Joshua please see the update.
